# Go - integration test uses test database connection

Tags: go, environment-variables, integration-testing

A go program connects to a database using a connection string. Currently that connection string is stored in an environment variable.

My challenge is to write a an automated test that exercises the program against a test database.

I thought I would set the connection string environment variable in the init() function of the test, but the main program's init() function is called before the test init(), so this does not work.

The workaround seems to be to default the connection string to the test database. If no environment variable is defined, use test; if it is defined (production), then use that instead.

Is there an alternative? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Is the db connection used by your program a global? If yes, just have your test create a test conn and set that as the value of the global var.

Comment: `var db = DB.getConnectionUsingEnvironmentVariable()`

Comment: This is in the main program. This currently panics. I could change it so that it doesn't attempt to create a connection if the environment variable is missing, and call the same code from the test, once I have set the environment variable. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Actually, just realised that if I move this line inside the function (instead of being global), then I _can_ set the environment variable in the test before the function is called. This seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: You said you want `an automated test that exercises the program against a test database` that means, I assume, your program is using a db connection, possibly `*sql.DB`, looks like its the `db` var from your snippet, if that's the case then to have your program talk to a test database you just need to, at the beginning of your test, create a new test connection and set it as the value of the `db` var, and so then when your program is using `db` to talk to the database it will be talkiing to the test one.

Comment: That's right - exactly as you say. The problem is that the code snippet is executed in the main program at start-up time (and fails due to missing environment variable). I can either implement the solution I just outlined, or leave var db as global, but uninitialised, and ensure that is it initialised by the time the function is called (by setting it in the test). Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to make the connection an uninitialised global. The function checks to see if the connection is nil - if so, it initialises it. The test has a setup() function which sets the connection to the integration test database - an alternative would be for the test to just set the environment variable.

Comment: if your using mysql i suggest https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock if you don't want to mock the structures yourself.